# PDFs and Mac Automator : There was a problem with the input to the Service. / The “[Quick Action name]” service could not be used

Tags: macos, automator

I'm trying to create Quick Action using Mac Automator to capture selected text. It fails when text is from PDF, but not other types of documents -- web pages for example.

The error messages are not helpful. Has anyone else encountered this problem? How was it resolved?

A Quick Action as simple as this produces the error on my Mac:
[image: Screen shot of Quick Action]

Comment: I have encountered exactly the same situation,[this](https://superuser.com/a/1619063/285075) can do a little bit of improvement.As the answer described,without input, `user-defined quick action` still cannot show up in the context menu ,only shortcut works.